# Issue in executing pyspark udf for simple time series forecasting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing a pyspark (2.4.8) job for performing time series predictions on a lot of models. I've a pandas df containing the model_ids and their corresponding path where the pickle files are present. I'll need to generate predictions using all these models.

My approach is to first convert the pandas df to a spark df. Then I'm planning to execute an udf per model-artifact-path to get the predictions, which are a simple list of integers.

Below is my high-level code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def inference_arima_with_udf(spark_session, model_metadata_pandas_df, start_date, end_date):    
    def get_preds(model_path, num_steps):
        # load model from model_metadata
        model = load_model(model_path)
        predictions = model.predict(num_steps)   # returns a numpy array of ints
        return predictions
    
    def get_schema():
        schema = StructType(
            [
                StructField("model_id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("model_artifacts_path", StringType(), True)
            ]
        )
        return schema
    
    num_steps = end_date - start_date + 1
    model_metadata_spark_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(model_metadata_pandas_df, get_schema())    
    get_preds_udf = F.udf(lambda mp: get_preds(mp, num_steps), ArrayType(IntegerType()))        
    model_metadata_spark_df = model_metadata_spark_df.withColumn('forecasts', get_preds_udf(F.col('model_artifacts_path'), 
                                                                                     F.lit(num_steps)))

    return model_metadata_spark_df
```

Problem is, once I execute this function, it returns this error:

> TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I've spent quite some time on this, but no luck so far. Any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: You are passing 2 arguments to `get_preds_udf` but `get_preds_udf` udf is only taking 1 arg, `mp`.   You can just call like `get_preds_udf(F.col('model_artifacts_path'))` because `num_steps` is static or receive 2 arguments in `get_preds_udf`

Comment: Thank you so much. Totally overlooked that part.